# Has English adopted any common morphemes from languages that are not Greek, Latin, or French?

Tags: linguistics, morphology

Has English adopted any common morphemes from any "exotic"-type languages?  By that, I'm trying to exclude our most frequent borrowings; i.e. French, Latin, and Greek, from which nearly all our suffixes and prefixes are borrowed — endings like *-ance*, *-ette*,  *-ience*, *-ium*, *-ology*, and innumerable more.  (Prefixes would be for example, *anti-*, *circ-*, *princ-)*  However, once you escape those big 3, I find it gets a lot harder; I personally can't think of any off the top of my head.  Can anyone else?

Comment: Hm, I just thought of one of one just now, a newly acquired one, from Chinese, _-fu_, which has been increasingly used as an appellation to mean "skill or expertise."

Comment: Ops, I forgot that one... Should I add it? By the way, +1 for the question. I didn't know of some of these morphemes :D

Comment: By *morphemes*, do you mean *affixes*? Any foreign load word typically contains non-English morphemes, of which you will understand there are a great many that do not come from the big three. Oh, and the line between affixes and other morphemes is extremely blurred. Most of your examples seem to be affixes, but *princ-* surely isn't: it is just a common root. // On a side note, if you consider frequency in speech, I'm not sure whether Greek would be third and not, say, Dutch (*boss*, anyone?).

Comment: Hmm adopted roots surely are morphemes so would fit the letter of the question but I think not the spirit of the question so hopefully the question is clarified rather than the root floodgates opened.

Comment: @Billare: for '-fu', you should make that a real answer.

Comment: @Mitch -- `-fu` is mostly jocular.  I don't know it that disqualifies it.

Comment: I second the nomination for *-fu*. Joke or no joke people are using it. You can't keep something out of the dictionary just for being funny (-:

Comment: @Cerberus I think by *morpheme* the question asker means [bound morpheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bound_morpheme)

Comment: @nohat: Yes, that seems likely; I didn't think of that term. Do you know what the difference would be between affixes and bound morphemes? Some say affixes cannot be lexical morphemes, while others say they can; if they can, affixes and bound morphemes would be the same, or am I missing something? (By the way, I'm not so sure the line between lexical and grammatical morphemes is that clear if you look at them diachronically...)

Comment: @Cerberus: This would be an excellent question for the linguistics SE when it appears! As for *-fu* I don't think it can exist on its own so I'd say it's a bound morpheme.

Comment: @Cerberus bound morphemes includes things like *cran-* (as in *cranberry*), *-tain* (as in *attain*, *obtain*, *contain*), *flat(e)* as in (*inflate*, *deflate*, *flatulent*), and *funct* (as in *function*, *defunct*, *perfunctory*), which are roots that obligatory require attachment to another morpheme; that is, they cannot stand alone. Some would argue that some of these morphemes’ status as independent morphemes is questionable and that *perfunctory* does not (anymore) share any morphemes with *function*.

Answer (score 14):

Yiddish: 'nik', as in "beatnik", no-goodnik, peacenik.

Comment: [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=beatnik) says the *-nik* suffix was, in the Sputnik days, imitative. So, it's Russian rather than Yiddish. (The *New Oxford American Dictionary* confirms, adding “perhaps influenced by the U.S. use of Yiddish *nik*”.)

Comment: @F'x: You're right, it has a Slavic origin.

Comment: @F'x: I forgot to say I mentioned it in my answer, in case you didn't notice. :D

Comment: @F'x: I think Etymonline is wrong. `-nik` is used in English almost exactly as it is used in Yiddish and not at all in any reminiscent of "sputnik".   The usages I'm most familiar with, like "nogoodnik" and "upstairsnik" (upstairs neighbor) predate Sputnik. [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-nik) just says the morpheme "experienced a surge" "after" the launch, but even that may be a *post hoc* error.  In 1958, Herb Caen called someone a "beatnik" in print (certainly drawing on his own Yiddish-speaking background, not the Soviet space program) and the rest was history.

Comment: @Malvolio: I don't know whether Yiddish have this ending, but it's pretty common in Russian Language (and in Slavic languages in general).

Comment: @Alenanno -- I'm here to tell you it *is* in Yiddish, and I cited three `-nik` words that definitely got to English through Yiddish (and those words have been productive of other words: "peacenik", "neatnik", "nudgenik").  Only one word, `sputnik`, seems to have come from any Slavic language and that word has not led to any others.

Comment: another: _refusenik_.

Comment: @Malvolio: Given the origins of Yiddish, and given that the way it is used in English is entirely consistent with how it is used in Slavic languages, it is almost certainly Slavic, possibly by way of Yiddish.

Comment: Nudnik and kibbutznik both came into English as whole words before Sputnik. Sputnik was then orders of magnitude more common, an explosion as stated. Other -nik words then began appearing. On Google Books there is a preview of *English word-formation* by Laurie Bauer with ten pages of chapter 8.2.4 on *-nik*. Go to page 255 or 256: http://books.google.com.au/books?id=R_AJmQNd-igC&pg=PA264&lpg=PA264&dq=offshootnik&source=bl&ots=csJhZ-DBod&sig=WMQBKMDxRmA0Jc214yDHlFyYV2Q&hl=en&ei=2AnbTdOfJIyuvgOCsKinDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=8.2.4.1&f=false

Comment: Wikipedia also has an entire article on *-nik* : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-nik

Answer (score 13):

> These ones are the ones I could find.
>
> - The link brings you to a more in depth description.
> - Between parentheses, you'll see the origin.
>
> The main page that I found at the beginning is "[English Morphemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aEnglish_morphemes)
>   ". I tried to order them in a *matching* order to fit your question. If you see something that doesn't fit, feel free to let me know.

---

> **Misc. origins**:

- **[-nik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-nik)** (slavic origin): The English suffix -nik is of Slavic origin. It approximately corresponds to the suffix "-er" and nearly always denotes an agent noun (that is, it describes a person related to the thing, state, habit, or action described by the word to which the suffix is attached). In the cases where a native English language coinage may occur, the "-nik"-word often bears an ironic connotation.
- **[-lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-lock)** (Old English): The suffix -lock in Modern English survives only in *[wedlock](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wedlock)*. It descends from Old English -lác which was more productive, carrying a meaning of "action or proceeding, state of being, practice, ritual".
- **"[Shm-reduplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shm-reduplication)"** (presumably Yiddish): Shm-reduplication is a form of reduplication in which the original word or its first syllable (**the base**) is repeated with the copy (**the reduplicant**) beginning with shm- (sometimes schm-), pronounced `/ʃm/`. The construction is generally used to indicate irony, derision or skepticism with respect to comments about the discussed object:

> **EXAMPLE:**
>   He's just a baby!
>   Baby-shmaby. He's already 5 years old!

The construction appears to have originated in Yiddish and was subsequently transferred to English, especially urban northeastern American English, by Yiddish speaking Jews. It is now known and used by many non-Jewish English speakers.

Comment: There was another one I saw recently... I can't remember the author at the moment though.

Comment: Many of these were not adopted but inherited. I considered anything that came from Old English to be part of the family by birth with no adoption papers necessary and hence not within the scope of the question.

Comment: @hippietrail: Those are not from Old English, to be exact, they came through it, but originally are from Proto-Germanic. If others agree with you about them being off topic, anyway, I'll remove them.

Comment: @Alenanno: Again Old English did not borrow/adopt from Proto-Germanic, Old English is a Germanic language, a descendant. From father to son to grandson is still a hand-me-down and not a souvenir brought home from abroad.

Comment: The Old English and Germanic morphemes are not adopted — otherwise every single word in English is adopted.  Circumfixes and suprafixes aren't borrowed either.  Connecting vowels (aka theme vowels) aren't morphemes; remember, morphemes have semantic meaning.  *N-* is not borrowed from another language.  *-Zilla* is an English innovation; it is formed by analogy with *Godzilla* — the *-zilla* morpheme was not borrowed from Japanese.

Comment: Answer Edited. @Hippietrail: I know of the descendance, I'll delete them. @Kosmonaut: That vowel is a morpheme, because it carries semantic meaning. The o in "neur-o-logy" is not the same as "speed-o-meter", don't you agree? Zilla doesn't come from Japanese strictly speaking, but it wasn't created in English, but borrowed from that movie.

Comment: That theme vowel carries semantic meaning?  And what is that meaning?  The *o* in *neurology* is part of *neuro*.  But the theme vowel *-o-* *ometer* words is there for purely morphophonological reasons: i.e. because the construction comes from Latin and always has a vowel between *meter* and the root morpheme.  In cases where the root already ends in a vowel, it doesn't show up, e.g. *calorimeter*.  If *-o-* is a morpheme then the *e* in past tense words is a morpheme (as in *heated*).

Comment: As I think you already know, _-ed_ is the morpheme there. Anyway, you're right, I checked better and I was wrong on that one... :)

Comment: I removed Zilla, just to be sure.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: I generally agree, though a (weakish) case could be made for *-o-* as a morpheme if semantic difference should be the criterion: *speed meter* might be considered semantically different from *speedometer*; you could say the *-o-* adds a sense of technicality, of a complicated device. // Note that *-o-* is of Greek origin: Latin would normally use *-i-*, as in *Luc-i-fer* or *man-i-fest*. Compounds consisting of several words that aren't common affixes are rarer in Latin than in Greek: the Romans would typically use a separate word in the genitive to qualify the head word.

Comment: @Cerberus: That is an argument that *ometer* in those particular constructions is a separate English morpheme from *-meter*, which is not totally crazy.  But to argue that *-o-* is a morpheme of English, you'd need to see it employed separately from *-meter* at the very least.  Of course a weakness in your "speed meter" example is that you are looking at the standalone word *meter* vs. the bound morpheme *-meter*, and so the subtle difference you suggest might well be due to the differences in those morphemes, rather than *ometer* being the morpheme (like e.g. *gentleman* vs. "gentle man").

Answer (score 11):

It's on the fringe but [***uber-***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uber-) has an English entry in Wiktionary.

**UPDATE**

Here's a couple more I found in *English word-formation* by Laurie Bauer:

- [***-ese***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ese) (from Italian) *Balinese*, *Nepalese*, *Vietnamese*
- [***-i***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-i#English) (from Arabic) *Bengali*, *Iraqi*, *Israeli*, *Pakistani*

Comment: as does [ur-](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ur-).

Comment: @Malvolio: *-ur* is also in Wiktionary but it's less of a fringe-dweller and I think you should submit it as an answer rather than a mere comment!

Answer (score 10):

hippietrail thinks I should point out that *ur-* (meaning "original", as in *urtext*) is another example.  Dictionaries say it comes from the German but I think it was at least reinforced by the name of the ancient Sumerian city [Ur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ur).

Answer (score 7):

This is a bit of a stretch, but the OED lists 'fest' -- as in 'filmfest,' 'gabfest,' and (obviously) 'oktoberfest' -- as having been borrowed from modern German. (For the apparently cognate 'festival' it offers a different etymology that passes through Old French and Medieval Latin to the Latin 'festīvus.')

Answer (score -1):

If you take your rule as being any productive (makes new words easily) affix that is not from the accepted literary/scientific neologism-making affixes you alluded to (that is, allowing from also from Latin/Greek/French but still keeping to the spirit of what you asked):

- *-athon*: any long extended activity. From marathon < Marathon (Gr) the town in ancient Greece. - sale-a-thon, dance-a-athon. sure this is Greek but...
- *du jour*:  From 'du jour' (Fr) 'of the day'. sure this is from French but...

Answer (score -3):

Ooh, I just thought of a good one: `-borne`.  As in "airborne" or "seaborne".  It comes from German.

Comment: Can you include a reference source?

Comment: @Billare -- uh, [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bear)?

Comment: Sorry I can't find any evidence that these come from German. The dictionaries I checked don't have separate entries for *-borne* as an adjective and state that *borne* is *airborne* is just from the  past participle of English *to bear*.

Comment: "bear" and "borne" both come from early German.  Was there a requirement it come *directly* from the foreign language?

Comment: If You mean Germanic or Proto-Germanic then all non-adopted words in English come from there too. Back in the deep mists of time there were no separate languages Afrikaans Danish Dutch English Flemish German Icelandic Norwegian Scots Swedish Yiddish. You don't adopt your own kin.

Comment: German is not the same as Germanic. Some loans apart, English does not come from any form of German.

Comment: @Colin File: Exactly. Etymonline and Wiktionary both say borne/bear come from Old English and not from German. Here is the path: Modern English *bear* ← Middle English *beren* “carry, bring forth” ← Old English *beran* “to carry, bear, bring” ← Proto-Germanic *beranan, *barōnan “to bear, carry” ...